# GRASS d.mon failing to connect to a monitor

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu

I'm running GRASS 6.4.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. I can't seem to get the monitor to work.

```
d.mon -L

name            description                    status
----            -----------                    ------
PNG             Create PNG file                not running
png1            Create PNG file                not running
png2            Create PNG file                not running
png3            Create PNG file                not running
png4            Create PNG file                not running
png5            Create PNG file                not running
png6            Create PNG file                not running
png7            Create PNG file                not running
gism            Create PNG file for gis.m      not running
HTMLMAP         Create HTML Image Map          not running
PS              Create PS file                 not running
ps1             Create PS file                 not running
ps2             Create PS file                 not running
ps3             Create PS file                 not running
ps4             Create PS file                 not running
ps5             Create PS file                 not running
ps6             Create PS file                 not running
ps7             Create PS file                 not running
(Thu Sep 28 21:12:20 2017) Command finished (0 sec)
```

I thought I could go 'd.mon start=X0', but it returns:

```
ERROR: no such monitor 'X0'
ERROR: No such monitor as <X0>
Problem selecting X0. Will try once more
ERROR: No such monitor as <X0>
```

X11 is installed and working, but how do I get monitors to appear in the list above?

Comment: That X11 is installed is not necessarily enough - if you compile yourself you also need to tell "configure" to actually use it. See https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu

Comment: That said, I'd strongly recommend to switch to GRASS GIS 7 since version 6 is several years behind in development (basically in maintenance mode).

Comment: In the the configure file, it looks like `ac_x_libraries` and `enable_w11` enable X11. I'll recompile and give it a go.

Comment: The ortho tool is almost complete in GRASS GIS 7.4 (to be released).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
d.mon start=wx0
```

More information [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/d.mon.html)

Comment: `GRASS 6.4.6 (1955_ortho_test):~ > d.mon start=wx0`
`ERROR: no such monitor 'wx0'`
`ERROR: No such monitor as <wx0>`
`Problem selecting wx0. Will try once more`
`ERROR: No such monitor as <wx0>`

Comment: Is wxpython installed (and used to compile GRASS)?

Comment: Note: In GRASS GIS 6 there is no wx monitor.